Is this circuit worth anything? What is the role of resistor R8?
I found this circuit somewhere (don't know what it's worth.) The intention is to send a signal when the microphone detects a clap. I think I get the general idea, but I still have some questions

What's the purpose of resistor R8?
Does this have a chance to produce a single electronic signal when we clap ? I expect the sound signal to be (quick) oscillations and I wouldn't be surprised if the output somehow has to be debounced to clean the signal.



R8 polarize the BJT transistor with some DC feedback. This is a stable polarization.

The circuit is worth it's components. When C5 charges up, it might not trigger Q1 any more.

@Justme Since the Q4 is somewhat turned on and its collector is neither at Vcc nor at ground level, the C5 should not get charged up so as to block any signal, and a positive signal/pulse on collector should always trigger the Q1.

@EdinFifić So the cap can't charge so that Q1 Vbe is always less that Vbe threshold? What would drain it, i.e. bias the Q1 side of the cap?

A common-emitter amplifier (with no emitter resistor) is really hard to bias correctly, to keep collector potential in between the two supply extremes:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left I apply a very precise 620mV at the base, which in this example is just the right amount to cause the transistor to conduct just the right amount of current to place collector potential \$V_{OUT}\$ near the supply mid-point of 2.5V.
On the right, I've raised base potential by only 0.1V, but that's enough to saturate the transistor, and \$V_{OUT}\$ plummets to near zero. It's very sensitive to changes in base potential.
To make matters worse, we usually use the power supply (5V here) to derive the require 620mV (using a potential divider for instance), and any fluctuation in that supply will cause that 620mV to vary.
Worse still, 620mV works for this transistor, but it will be different (always somewhere near 700mV, though) for every other transistor on the planet, even those from the same manufacturing batch.
Even worse, that value of 620mV is heavily dependent on the transistor's temperature, so the circuit may well work in a 20° office, but fail completely outside at 10°C.
We can let the transistor find its own "bias" base voltage with your R8 (my R2 here):

simulate this circuit
Imagine that something happens to perturb base potential, to cause it to lower slightly. The collector responds by rising in potential by a much larger amount (gain is high, and the common emitter arrangement inverts the signal). That in turn raises base potential, in opposition to the original perturbation. Vice versa, a perturbation that raises base potential results in collector potential falling fast, which will "fight" against the initial perturbation.
This is "negative feedback" (via R2), which causes the system to settle in an equilibrium, where the collector hovers at whatever potential is necessary (near the supply mid-point of +2.5V in this case) to keep the base near 0.7V.
It's weak feedback (1MΩ is a large resistance), so we can still disturb the equilibrium slightly, to have the collector respond with much greater amplitude. It's still an amplifier, but now its collector is "centered" near the supply midpoint, and able to swing upwards towards +5V, and downwards towards 0V, around the equibilibrium point.
Yes, this circuit could work to respond to a "clap". Your "mic_amp" node will certainly rise and fall dramatically in potential, in response to loud sounds at the microphone.

Thanks a lot, that's very clear

The circuit is worth whatever the purpose you need it for.
R8 is meant to polarize the transistor Q4, in other words to keep it slightly turned on or it wouldn't work because the microphone signal would likely not be high enough to trigger it.
If the circuit doesn't work as well as it should, you could use a voltage divider on the base of the Q4, basically something like one 100k resistor from Vcc to base, and another 100k resistor from base to ground (negative side of power supply voltage.
Keeping Q4 biased so that it is slightly on means that it will need a much smaller signal to produce a current through it.
I would pay attention to capacitor C4, as its value might be too low to transfer a sufficient signal to transistor Q4. If you see no signal or pulses at the collector of Q4 and at the output of this circuit, you should experiment with C4 values from 1nF to 1uF.
Regarding your last question, whether this circuit has a chance to produce a signal and whether the signal needs to be cleaned up or modified to make it useful, that really depends on what kind of a circuit or load is it going to.
For example, if it's an LED, you could place it in series with R1 and that might be it.
If it's a circuit that needs a pulse of limited amplitude, you would need to limit the amplitude, and so on.
So, it would help if you tell us what you need it for.

Made with microcap v12.
Here is the behavior of R8.

You can see that the BJT is "well" polarized with a 1 MegOhm resistor.
The Vc voltage is around 2.3 V which is ok for all temperatures.
Note that your Q1 is not "well" polarized and it could be "stuck" ...
As already pointed.
When the switch is on, voltage output returns faster ... (red curve).


How much are great ideas worth?

Is this circuit worth anything?

There are circuit solutions that are extremely universal and conceptual. They can be implemented with various devices (vacuum tubes, transistors, op-amps, etc.) With them, all sorts of seemingly different circuit solutions can be explained. That is why they are worth studying well.
The great idea behind R8
Such a fundamental idea lies behind the simple connection of resistor R8 between the collector and base of Q4 transistor. It is known as a voltage-type negative feedback. As the name suggests, this is a method for maintaining a constant voltage. Let's explore this concept in a step-by-step manner.
Building and exploring the circuit
No feedback
A transistor Q in the schematic below converts the input base-emitter voltage Vin into an output collector current. To get an output voltage Vout, we pass the current through a collector resistor Rc. So this combination of a transistor and a resistor connected in a voltage-divider configuration represents the most elementary transistor voltage amplifier.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Diode-connected transistor
If we connect the base of the transistor to its collector, the mechanism of negative feedback comes into play, which in this case consists of the following.
Initially, the entire supply voltage is applied through resistor Rc to the base-emitter junction. The transistor starts to increase its collector current, as a result of which its collector voltage decreases until equilibrium is reached around 0.7 volts. So, when connected in this way, the transistor behaves like a forward-biased diode. This circuit finds applications in providing bias voltage, current mirrors, and more.

simulate this circuit
The circuit resembles an op-amp voltage follower with a 629 mV input voltage.

simulate this circuit
Resistor feedback (OP's circuit)

What's the purpose of the R8 resistor ?

If we connect a resistor Rb (R8 in your circuit) between the collector and the base, we make it difficult for the transistor and force it to reach equilibrium at a higher value of 5 V collector voltage. Figuratively speaking, the resistor acts as a disturbance for the transistor.

simulate this circuit
In your circuit, this trick is used to set a stable (independent of temperature and other factors) output bias voltage, also called "setting the operating or quiescent point". This is done by setting the base current.
Voltage-divider feedback ("rubber Zener diode")
A more stable operating point can be set by voltage. For this purpose, we add another resistor R1 to make a voltage divider. An additional advantage is the lower R2 resistance value.

simulate this circuit
The circuit resembles an op-amp non-inverting amplifier with a 606 mV input voltage.

simulate this circuit
Inverting amplifier (OP's circuit)
We can apply an input voltage through another R1 resistor. It can be negative or AC through a capacitor (as in your circuit).

simulate this circuit
This circuit resembles an op-amp inverting amplifier with a -3.892 V input voltage.

simulate this circuit
